# combine year and quarter into DateTime using Pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series

My data consists of
`Year` and `Quarter`. I would like to make it into the DateTime index. such as YYY-MM-DD. 
thanks

Comment: Can you add example data?

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'q':['2020-Q1', '2030-Q3']})
    df
```

Coerce to datetime

```
df['q']=pd.to_datetime(df['q'])
df
```

Comment: Is this what you needed?